# What do people with bachelor's degrees in humanities actually end up doing?

Tags: career-path, humanities, political-science, history

If someone majors in political science or international relations or history, what do they end up actually doing as a career?

I've found numerous sites that give the obvious answers what they *can* do, but to date no site that says what they actual do.

It's all fine and dandy thinking that an International Studies degree will prepare you for a career as a diplomat, but if 95% of graduates end up selling life insurance, or filling out form 2773A-11 for some bureaucracy, I may want to make a different set of choices.

Comment: I have a bachelor's degree in History and one in Philosophy. I am now assistant professor in Computer Science. Even if you end up doing something that is not directly connected to your humanities degree, they can help you to face a variety of situation, develop some skills, and I like to believe that they can sometimes make you a better human beings.

Comment: @aparente001 I have reviewed 2638 Closed Votes on Workplace SE. Based on my experience, this question will be closed there for certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any large-scale surveys on the topic.

However, many universities conduct regular surveys on their alumni, to understand where they end up working. You can find them on [Google](https://www.google.at/search?q=political+science+employment+survey). Here is one [example](https://www.statsvet.su.se/english/education/study-information/2.29527) from the University of Stockholm on political science alumni:

> Public administration, state level (44 percent)
>
> Public administration, local and regional level (14 percent)
>
> Private companies (14 percent)
>
> NGO's (5 percent)
>
> Universities and university colleges (5 percent)
>
> Political party/party organisation (4 percent)
>
> Think tanks (4 percent)
>
> International organisations (EU, UN, etc.) (3 percent)
>
> Media (2 percent).

As you can see, in this particular University, the outcome is indeed what one would expect.

Answer (score 7):

The reason certain courses (engineering, law, medicine) are referred to as 'professional courses' is that they prepare one  for a particular profession, and that is the primary goal of the course.
In any other course, it is a good idea to assume that you are being taught various skills, but not necessarily being prepared for a career. To expect a career out of a humanities degree may therefore be misguided.  Best to look at it as a stepping stone that could lead you in a multitude of directions.

Answer (score 1):

Although a specific job path for a humanities graduate can be wildly different from person to person. Many jobs in policy, research or marketing are good choices for a well-rounded humanities grad. The degree program is meant to help you learn how to communicate clearly, think critically and make reasoned choices -- skills that can be beneficial for just about any career. Here are a few of the possible job choices for humanities majors:

Craft and Fine Artists ,
Social and Human Service Assistants ,
Community Health Workers ,
Advertising and sales agents ... etc.

Teaching, art historian at a museum , archeologist and so on might be a better option